# How install Java runtime like openjdk-8 in QNX environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

I've QNX environment QNX localhost 7.1.0 AWS_Graviton2aarch64le.
In this environment how to install OpenJDK version 11 or 8.? is any command line to install QNX?
For an example: Debian, Ubuntu, etc.
On the command line, type:
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
The openjdk-8-jre package contains just the Java Runtime Environment.

I downloaded eclipse-SDK-2.0.1-qnx-photon.tar.xz but its not working as its a linux package